# JLabel not validating

Tags: java, swing, window, jframe, jlabel

I set a JLabel equal to a string that is reading information from a file and whenever I want to add it to my JFrame and load up the class the JLabel wont show up. The string intromsgstring is working and I know that because I tested it with a System.out.println().

Here is the code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.color.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
public class intro extends JFrame{

//Variables 
public Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20);
public String playername;
public String intromsgstring;
public JLabel intromsg = new JLabel(intromsgstring);
public JFrame window = new JFrame();
//Screen Settings
public intro(){
setSize(1100,650);
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setResizable(false);
setVisible(true);
setTitle("TEST");
setBackground(Color.BLACK);
}

//Paint Method
public void paint(){
    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new                        File("/Users/AlecStanton/Desktop/op1/name.txt"));
         intromsgstring = "Oh! Hello there. Welcome to the land of lylaid. So your name is " + scan.nextLine();
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     //Intro Box
    intromsg.setFont(font);
    intromsg.setAlignmentX(170);
    intromsg.setAlignmentY(535);
    window.add(intromsg);
}

//Object
public static void main(String[] args) {
      intro intro = new intro();
    }
```

Comment: How would I fix my progarm then?

Comment: I am guessing that I should add the scanner in another method then?

Comment: But why isint my jlabel appearing on the jframe if its loading content from the fle correctly?

Comment: You're taking a class in programming aren't you?

Comment: 1) A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 3) Instead of painting in a top level container such as `JFrame`, add a `JPanel` & do custom painting in the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method.  Also return a sensible preferred size for the custom component, to assist the layout manager.

Answer (score 4):

You've got several problems with your code including

- You're overriding a JFrame's paint method, something that should almost never be done
- You're using a Scanner and trying to read in Files in a paint or paintComponent method.
- You're trying to add in a component in a paint or paintComponent method.
- You create a Scanner object but never read the file with it.
- You jave two JFrames, `this` which is the current object your intro class and which is being displayed and window which is a JFrame variable, which is receiving the JLabel and which is never displayed.
- You need to learn and follow Java naming conventions so that others can better understand your code. Class names begin with upper case and method and variable names with lower case.
- You will want to improve your code formatting, again so that others can more readily understand your code. This includes your code indentation and use of white-space (one blank line is plenty).

You never add components or work with Scanners or files in a paint or paintComponent method. Not unless you wish to make your program completely unresponsive. The paint method should almost never be overridden, and a JPanel's paintComponent method should be overridden to do painting and painting only.

Use your Scanner in a constructor or non-paint method.
Please also check out the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) for more details on how to use this library.

Comment: Could you include some program code to fix this pardon my request but I am new to java and am not familiar to object oriented programing.

Comment: I know php but thats different

Comment: @user2540802: I'm not even sure what you're trying to accomplish. You really need to go through some of the Swing tutorials first. You must learn Java and Swing first before you can try to use them. There's no short cuts.

Comment: But why isint my jlabel appearing on the jframe if its loading content from the fle correctly?

Comment: @user2540802: also you're adding your JLabel to the wrong JFrame. Please see edit to answer.